# How do I switch the image files I want to see in a JavaFXML Button?

Tags: css, javafx

I am trying to toggle a button between two states. One state is to display an 
image of a red circle, the other state being an image of a blue circle. When the user clicks the button it should toggle between the states. I have set
style in my css to accommodate the button:

```
#button-debit {
    -fx-background-image: url("images/redButton.jpg");     
}

#button-credit {
    -fx-background-image: url("images/blueButton.png");
}
```

To see if this works I have tried just to transform from red to blue by doing this:

```
@FXML
  private void handledborcrBtn() {
    dborcrBtn.setId("button-credit");
  }
```

However the result is not as expected. The red button image stays in place with the blue one underneath it, but the blue image is split up into several parts.

I think I remember a 'repaint' method from javax Swing but there seems to be more complicated with JavaFXML and I'm having trouble getting this to work properly.

Comment: Why not just toggle the `graphic` property of the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with the ToogleBotton

```
.toggle-button {
  -fx-graphic: url('icons.jpg');
}

.toggle-button:selected {
  -fx-graphic: url('othericon.png');
}
```